# Button is inside update panel. but every button click full page postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax

In my code for every droup down is in update panel.it is not postback. for every button click full postback is occure. but my buttons are in update panel.i tried in trigger asynpostback, in that case server side message is not displayed. i want that msg also.

my code is:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <table align="center" style="border: thin solid #FF0000" width="80%">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="Black" style="color: #FFFFFF">
                Schedule New Batch
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <div>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Style="font-weight: 700; color: #FF0000;"
                        Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSucess" runat="server" Style="font-weight: 700; color: #006600;
                        background-color: #FFFFFF;" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style44" align="right">
                Technology<span class="style23">*</span> :
            </td>
            <td class="style45">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTechnology" runat="server" Width="155px" Class="valid" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTechnology_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="True" Height="23px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style49" align="right">
                Courses<span class="style23">*</span> :
            </td>
            <td class="style50">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourse" runat="server" Width="155px" Class="valid" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCourse_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="True" Height="23px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style9" align="right">
                Faculty<span class="style23">*</span> :
            </td>
            <td class="style47">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFaculty" runat="server" Width="155px" Class="valid" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFaculty_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="True" Height="23px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style44" align="right">
                Timing<span class="style24">*</span> :
            </td>
            <td class="style45">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTiming" runat="server" Width="155px" Height="23px" AutoPostBack="True"
                            Class="valid" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTiming_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" />
                        <cc1:modalpopupextender id="btnAdd_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" cancelcontrolid="btnCancleInsertTime"
                            dynamicservicepath="" enabled="True" popupcontrolid="Panel1" targetcontrolid="btnAdd">
                    </cc1:modalpopupextender>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style44" align="right">
                Start Date<span class="style23">*</span> :
            </td>
            <td class="style45">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel6" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertdate" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="16px" Class="valid"></asp:TextBox>
                        <cc1:calendarextender id="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtInsertdate"
                            format="yyyy-MM-dd">
                    </cc1:calendarextender>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style51">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="style45">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="text-align: right">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSchedule" runat="server" Text="Schedule" Style="font-weight: 700;
                        margin-left: 0px;" Width="81px" Height="24px" OnClick="btnSchedule_Click" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnreset" runat="server" OnClick="btnreset_Click" Style="font-weight: 700"
                            Text="Reset" Width="67px" CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnreset" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" aline="center">
                    <table style="border: thin solid #FF0000; background: #7F8778">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="style53">
                                Please Add a Time
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="color: #FF0000" class="style53">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInsertTime" runat="server" Width="124px"></asp:TextBox>
                                &nbsp; EX: 09:15AM
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel7" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <td align="center" class="style53">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnInsertTime" runat="server" Text="Add Time" Width="73px" OnClientClick="return InsertTime()"
                                            OnClick="btnInsertTime_Click" class="cancel" />
                                        &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancleInsertTime" Text="Cancel" Width="55px" runat="server" class="cancel" />
                                    </td>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You forget to specify what button you click, where is it. You have too many UpdatePanels. Each one is act alone. Ether use only one UpdatePanel under witch you have all your controls that you like to update using it.

Comment: btnreset and btnInsertTime button clicks always post back.

Comment: If i using one Update Panel "btnSchedule" this button click execute server side code without validation

Comment: every droup down selected Index changed i want server side code

Comment: I am so glad I refrain from using UpdatePanel...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to register that controls with script manager like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(ddlTechnology);
  ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(ddlCourse);
}
```

Comment: In that case server side code is executed without validations